# Change order or add spacing to PlantUML ER diagrams

Tags: database, erd, entity-relationship, plantuml

I just start using PlantUML for my modeling needs. Unfortunately, I cannot find a way to change the order of entities or add some spacing so things like in the picture below do not happen.

[image: Overlapping crowfeet]

The common ways through adding vertical pipes like ||| or ||40|| do not work. Also tried to abuse some legacy HTML, but nothing seems to work for me. You guys have any ideas?

Comment: Some code showing the problem would be welcome.

Comment: There is not that much to show, but you're right. It consists of `entity TableName {...}` and relations such as `Table1 |o--|{ Table2`. The are no specialities to it. Just basics as described on PlantUML's page for ERD (http://plantuml.com/ie-diagram)

Comment: Still a small example plus the version of plantuml you are using would be very useful.